# Getting back 'not in the index'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

This is from DataCamp exercise and worked correctly on website as well as the PyCharm Interpreter

```
# Pre-defined lists
names = ['United States', 'Australia', 'Japan', 'India', 'Russia', 'Morocco', 'Egypt']
dr = [True, False, False, False, True, True, True]
cpc = [809, 731, 588, 18, 200, 70, 45]

import pandas as pd

# Create dictionary my_dict with three key:value pairs: my_dict
my_dict = {"country": names, "drives_right": dr, "cars_per_cap": cpc}

# Build a DataFrame cars from my_dict: cars
cars = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

# Print cars
print(cars)


print("\n*Using 'loc':")
print(cars.loc[[1]])
```

*Breaks right here*

```
print(cars.loc[[names]])
```

*says 'names' not in the index

Comment: Even using the country names brings back 'not in the index'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is `filter by column value(s)`. You can simply do `[1]` or set the index of the data frame like `[2]`.

###### `[1]` Filter by column values

```
print(cars[cars['country'] == names])
# or print(cars[cars['country'].isin(names)])
```

###### `[2]` Indexed DataFame

```
cars_indexed = cars.set_index("country")
cars_indexed.loc[names]
```

###### Results

---

`[result 1]`

[image]

`[result 2]`

[image]

p.s.
[`pandas loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is primarily label based

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), you can see that `df.loc` will access elements from the index. In your case, the index is `0,1,...,6`. That is why it gives you the error - the index simply doesn't have those elements. If you were to define the index as an array of strings, like they do in the documentation (I recommend you check out the example) you could get the rows with those string indices.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.loc` is used to select index or column header by label. `names` is column value. If you want to select rows that values are in list, you can try `isin` with boolean masking.

```py
print(cars[cars['country'].isin(names)])
```